# Does the Mavic Mini 2 drone support the DJI FPV controller and goggles?

Tags: first-person-view, dji, compatibility, fpv-goggles, dji-mini-2

The drone: [Official Website](https://www.dji.com/ca/mini-2) | [Where I'm buying it from](https://www.costco.ca/dji-mini-2-bundle.product.100804126.html)

I am looking for a drone for a class at school, but we need one under 250 grams, and that supports First Person View, so that we can use VR goggles to fly it. This one has the video quality to support it, and you can connect your phone to the controller and stream live video, so does that mean we could connect VR googles to the phone and fly in first person? I don't think it works with the actual DJI first person controllers and headset, but I am not 100% sure.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: No Mavic is compatible with the DJI FPV system.

Comment: Ok good to know what it doesn't work with the DJI official FPV. Do you know if I could use other vr googles to do FPV with the phone display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @strepto said, the Mavic Mini 2 is not supported by DJIs FPV system, they are only promoting their (very expensive) [DJI FPV drone](https://store.dji.com/no/shop/dji-fpv-series) for FPV flying these days.

There are however various hacks to use 3rd party VR goggles with the Mini 2, you can read more about it in this thread on the DJI forum: https://forum.dji.com/thread-228895-1-1.html